# Weblogic LogicalConnection cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection

Tags: java, oracle, connection, datasource

I am getting ClassCastException while creating oracle.sql.Clob object.

Error :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JTAConnection_weblogic_jdbc_wrapper_XAConnection_oracle_jdbc_driver_LogicalConnection cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection
    at oracle.sql.CLOB.createTemporary(CLOB.java:868)
    at oracle.sql.CLOB.createTemporary(CLOB.java:828)
```

Java Code:

```
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
DataSource dsds = (DataSource)ic.lookup("valid_ds_name");
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
CLOB clob = CLOB.createTemporary(connection, false, CLOB.MODE_READWRITE);
```

weblogic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app">
  <context-root>/PNPRESTAPI</context-root>
  <container-descriptor>
        <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
    </container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

jar included:

```
ojdbc6.jar
```

Comment: You should have a conflict between your jdbc driver and the one provided by weblogic server. Do you really need to embed ojdbc6.jar in your application ?

Comment: Try CLOB.createTemporary(connection.unwrap(), false, CLOB.MODE_READWRITE);